# php to Allow Download only if session / cookie is active

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have provided a straight download link in my site as below.

```
<a href="myfile.pdf">Download here</a>
```

This file is accessible to every one. But i want to restrict this based on logged in users.

Say an user have an active session / cookie upon successful login as below.

```
$_SESSION['login'] = 1  or $_COOKIE['login'] = 1
```

even if set following condition, **people can manually type http://web.com/myfile.pdf and able to download the file...**

```
if($_SESSION['login']===1 && $_COOKIE['login']===1){
    echo '<a href="myfile.pdf">Download here</a>';
}
```

**Other Anonymous users should not be able to access the file.**

Comment: Use an if  statement to check the session/cookie and output accordingly

Comment: Create a php script that checks the session variable, reads the file and sends out force download headers. There are a thousand articles on SO about how to do this.

Comment: @ElefantPhace : even if set, anyone can manually type the link and get the file

Comment: Iff they know the filename, yes

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : how should i make it "on click" without reloading !

Comment: When you click the link, it goes to the php script for the file and if the download is authorized, a download dialog pops up. The user doesn't see the next screen as a page. They automatically stay on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it were me I would use something like this to hide the link entirely from the not logged in users

```
if($_SESSION['login']===1 || $_COOKIE['login']===1){
    echo '<a href="myfile.pdf">Download here</a>';
}
```

If you are looking for specific download denying based on the session after the link is clicked, you will have to setup some type of script to handle the above code and return the file you want.

EDITED:

OK, then link it to a script that retrieves the file from a non-accessible location and feeds it back with the same if/then statement.

Something like

filedownload.php?filename=foo.bar

And then filedownload.php would look something like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']===1 && $_COOKIE['login']===1){

$file_dir = "/some/dir/";
$file = $file_dir . 'foo.bar';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
} else {
    echo "You need to login to download this file.";
}
?>
```

This was copied directly from the PHP manual. And added the if/then statement.

Comment: even if set, anyone can manually type the link and get the file

Comment: it says, Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: @logan, that script should be the only thing in the entire page. Nothing else. Not even a space before `<?php`

Comment: then you must have something else wrong with your script. This checks if the session and cookie are set. If so, downloads the file, if not, shows the error message.

Make sure you used session_start(); on the filedownload.php file.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn : it works now.. but what if want to display some custom text in the page ?

Comment: You would want to display the text on another script and use something like a meta refresh or javascript to forward the user to the download page. You can't display a message on the same page as the download script because anything output before the header will throw an error and anything output after the header will be included in the downloaded file.

Comment: If you don't mind, please change your downvote to an upvote if this solved your question.

Comment: @CalvinK : Thanks :) I have done it., but there is no need to downvote my question as well !! because i have explained it well; you can remove downvote!